# How to use Xdebug with Laravel on Nginx with PHPStorm on Mac?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

Guide on how to setup XDebug with PHPStorm.

Versions:

- PHP 7.0
- PHPStorm 2016.3.2
- XDebug 2.5
- OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This guide is only for PHP7, Mac El Capitan, PHPStorm 2016.3

1. Install brew http://brew.sh/
2. Install php7 `brew install php70`
3. Install nginx

   Guide -  http://learnaholic.me/2012/10/10/installing-nginx-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

   Config - https://gist.github.com/kmaxat/c07795ab88677efb843686d075fafa9e
4. `brew install php70-xdebug`
5. Create info.php file in public folder of laravel:

   info.php: `<?php phpinfo();`
6. Edit file `/usr/local/etc/php7.0/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini`

   `zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php70-xdebug/xdebug.so"
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
   xdebug.remote_port = 9001
   xdebug.scream=0
   xdebug.show_local_vars=1
   xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM`
7. Restart nginx `sudo nginx -s reload` or `brew services restart nginx`
8. Restart php-fpm `brew services restart php70`
9. Go to localhost/info.php, you should be able to see xdebug. Part of the image:

[image: List item]

10. Setup your CLI interpreter. PHPStorm -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP

[image]

11. Click on '...' next to CLI interpreter. If above steps are done properly, you should be able to see this:

[image]

12. Setup Server: 
    Run -> Edit Configurations -> ... (next to server).

[image]

13. Setup Edit configuration
    Run -> Edit Configurations -> + -> PHP Web Application. Choose created server, set name

[image]

14. In Toolbar select created sever, then click on "Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections".

[image]

15. Set breakpoint at public/index.php

[image]

16. In toolbar click "Debug 'ServerName'"

Comment: Small note: you seems to configure "DBGp Proxy" ... but do not use it in any way. Why trying to configure it then? To confuse those who will read this manual even more (in case if they will have some issues)?

Comment: Right! My mistake, fixed it.

Comment: By the way since `.dev` is a legit gTLD it may not work as expected. Here is the first result of relevant Google search link https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/